# text replace in python

Tags: python, string

I have had written text file in which I have  statements like these :

```
WriteByte(0x6000, 0x28);    // Register Value ...    

WriteByte(0x6002, 0x02);    //      

WriteByte(0x6004, 0x08);    //
```

I have to replace 0x28 with a user given value as an input
This means I have replace 0x28 with usr_value which may be 0x35 or 0x38 etc..
Also I also cant count on there being only 0x28 it coould be any other value whose contents are to be replaced by user given content.
Also since the text file is hand written it could have extra spaces or not

```
WriteByte(0x6000,0x28); // Register Value ...
```

or

```
WriteByte( 0x6000 , 0x28);  // Register Value ...
```

I tried using `string.replace` but it may not work for all combinations.
What's the best way of doing this apart from using Regular expressions ?

Comment: Why "apart from regular expressions?" Those seem like the sensible approach.

Comment: Yes you are right it can be solved by using Regular Expressions but I was wondering if there was another way. Regular expressions are difficult newbies to understand.

Comment: Good opportunity to overcome your newbie status, then :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the discussion below, if you want to find all the second arguments to WriteBytes and prompt for replacing, you can do something like this:

1. parse the file to find all the 2nd arguments to WriteBytes, using a regular expression, and store them in a set (which will handle duplicates for you)
2. for all the values you've seen, prompt the user for the replacement value, and store that in a dictionary
3. read the file again, and perform the replacements, storing the modified lines in a list, together with the unmodified lines
4. write the data back to disk.

Sample code:

```
import re

filename = '/tmp/toto.txt'

write_byte_re= r'WriteByte\([^,]+,\s*([^\)]+)\)'

# look for all potential substitutions
search_values = set()
f = open(filename)
for line in f:
    print line
    match_object = re.match(write_byte_re, line)
    if match_object is None: # nothing found, keep looking
        continue
    else:
        search_values.add(match_object.group(1)) # record the value

f.seek(0) # rewind file

substitutions = {}
for value in search_values:
    print "What do you want to replace '%s' with? (press return to keep as is)"
    new_value = raw_input('> ')
    if new_value != '': 
        substitutions[value] = new_value

changed_lines = []
for line in f:
    match_object = re.match(write_byte_re, line)
    if match_object is not None: 
        value = match_object.group(1)
        if value in substitutions: # not in the dictionary if the user said nothing
            new_value = substitutions[value]
            # modify line
            line = re.sub('\b%s\b' % value, new_value, line)
    changed_lines.append(line)

f.close()

# write output
f = open(filename, 'w')
f.writelines(changed_lines)
f.close()
```

You can avoid reading the file twice at the cost of a slightly more complicated code (left as an exercise to the reader)

Comment: I am trying to understand your solution.  what do I give in the search_str ? Because I don't what the current value is in the file. The file may be having WriteByte(0x6000, 0x28) or WriteByte(0x6000, 0x30) which I have to replace by my own

Comment: yes but my question is I wont know what the current value is at the time the function registry_replace is called. I cant use registry_replace('filename.txt', '0x25', '0x35') because I don't what that value is it not necessarily be 0x25 so I can't just write '0x25' Whatever the currently written value, I need to replace it by the new value given by the user for example new_value = raw_input()

Comment: The old value is present in the txt file and is not known to the user while the new value I get is from the user so I can't ask the user which value he wants to replace

Comment: English is not my first language so excuse my lack of clarity. As I said my question in the beginning "Also I also cant count on there being only 0x28 it coould be any other value whose contents are to be replaced by user given content."